# not ok PhantomJS exited unexpectedly

Tags: continuous-integration, gruntjs, phantomjs, karma-runner, testem

`$ testem ci`

```
not ok 1 PhantomJS - Browser "phantomjs /home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.12/lib/node_modules/testem/assets/phantom.js http://localhost:7357/6092" exited unexpectedly.

1..1
# tests 1
# pass  0
# fail  1
```

`$ phantomjs --version`

```
2014-07-28T00:24:22 [WARNING] Unable to load library icui18n "Cannot load library icui18n: (libicui18n.so.48: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
2014-07-28T00:24:22 [WARNING] phantomjs: cannot connect to X server
```

What's wrong?

`testem` command works fine and all the tests pass in `Chrome`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was a bad phantomJS installation.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove phantomjs
$ npm uninstall phantomjs -g
$ npm install phantomjs -g
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error, tried uninstalling and installing three times, no luck. Any other ideas? `phantomjs --version` causes `/usr/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`