# not ok 1 PhantomJS exited unexpectedly when running `ember test` on CI

Tags: ember.js, phantomjs, ember-cli

Since updating to ember-cli 1.13.8 and Ember 2.0.0 (from 1.13.1 / 1.12.x) I can't get the test suite to run on CircleCI, because of the error:

```
not ok 1 PhantomJS - Browser "phantomjs /home/ubuntu/app-name/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/testem/assets/phantom.js http://localhost:7357/7887" exited unexpectedly.
1..1
tests 1
pass  0
fail  1
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm test returned exit code 1
```

It used to work before and what is weird, it works locally (OS X El Capitan, PhantomJS 2.0). On CircleCI it also runs on 2.0 version which is installed the following way:

```
$ sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install libicu52
$ curl --output /home/ubuntu/bin/phantomjs-2.0.1-linux-x86_64-dynamic https://s3.amazonaws.com/circle-support-bucket/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.0.1-linux-x86_64-dynamic
$ chmod a+x /home/ubuntu/bin/phantomjs-2.0.1-linux-x86_64-dynamic
$ sudo ln -s --force /home/ubuntu/bin/phantomjs-2.0.1-linux-x86_64-dynamic /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
```

Tried also downloading it from the Travis, but still the same thing happened.

Any idea what's the cause and how to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24985511/1190

Answer (score 2):

Try running phantomjs individually to find out which dependency is failing, I had the same issue on a Docker container and after running it i found out I needed an extra library to run it.

I was lacking the following dependencies on Ubuntu

`libgtk2.0-0 libidn11 libglu1-mesa`

Comment: this works for me and it's strange that this information isn't in the phantomjs docs or set as required dependencies for the node package

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but didn't fork for me, anyway, will do some further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually after updating Ember to 2.3.1 PhantomJS started to work without any problems, no idea what's the real reason behind this, but if anyone experiences this issue, try updating Ember and check again.